# How to Add/Remove databases on HSQL server dynamically?

Tags: java, desktop-application, hsqldb, lan

In my java based desktop application project,i need to create/remove new databases dynamically. I have implemented it properly for standalone machine. Now i am implementing my desktop application on LAN(Local Area Network) by running HSQLDB in server mode. I just want to know is it possible to and How to create/remove databases from HSQL server dynamically ? Thank You.